# Why is the ILS16 approach at KSKF not available in my Garmin 430W?

Tags: avionics, approach, ils, gns430

I am doing flight instruction on the San Antonio area (Texas) and I've been shooting different approches on the vecinity airports.

One of the approaches I usually execute is the ILS 16 at KSKF, which is a military and civilian airport. Yes you can land there and do fuel on the self service pump.

Everything was okay until the last garmin database update in which they removed the ILS approach. When you select the approaches on the GPS the only available ones are the RNAV approaches. I looked into the NOTAMs and there is nothing published there, I am still able to request the approach and do it with the VHF Nav Instruments, but was cool for students to monitor what was going on on the GPS as well.

Does anyone know why the approach is not able to be selected on the GPS?

Note: The GPS Database is current

Comment: This is a good question, although it might be best to contact Garmin support. It could be an error or other issue with their database or software. The ILS16 approach is there for me in Garmin Pilot, FWIW.

Comment: Thanks for oyur answer

Answer (score 1):

There are two ILS approaches for runway 16. Both of them had amendments on 13 Aug 20. Therefore, the IAP charts that were in the database are no longer valid. They expired. It would be interesting to know the effective date of your last Garmin update. That could affect what approaches you are able to see.

I am unable to pull up the former IAP charts at this time. It would also be interesting to see what has changed. At the KTKI airport, the decommissioning of the MELISA NDB was enough to require a complete change of the ILS approach. Melissa was the Final Approach Fix. You were to notify ATC when you were Inbound inside of the FAF. The NDB has been replaced by the JIPUK waypoint.

This is a good lesson for new pilots. Read the entire IAP chart (including the borders) and check the effective dates.

Comment: Hi Dean, sorry I tried to modify your comment instead of mine. I've just clarified that the GPS database is current. Thanks

Comment: @IvanParra - Hey, no problem. Though, my question still is when was the effective date of the database. If the database effective date was 10Aug20 and the chart effective date is 13Aug20, there is a chance that the chart will not show until the next update. If memory serves me correctly, they update every 28 days.

Comment: I have to check that, thanks for your answer. Although, thinking about it,  we always keep the DB updated, so, if it was on the previous DB why it is not on the new DB, there shouldn't be a gap between expiration of one DB and release date of the other one. Anyhow, I will check

Comment: @IvanParra - it is not the expiration date of the previous database versus the effective date of the new database you should check out. It is the expiration date of the old IAP chart versus the effective date of the new database. Did the chart expire between the effective date of the new database and the future effective date of the next database release? When a chart expires, Garmin May make the chart unavailable for use. Even between updates. I know that Foreflight does.

Comment: No, the chart is still available on foreflight and the DB was updated with an effective date that is after the chart changes. I have sent an email to Garmin

Comment: @IvanParra - Curious, you will have to post the answer when you hear back from Garmin. By the way, I was talking about the old expired chart being no longer available in Foreflight. The updated/amended chart is available.

Comment: I will thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I finally received an answer from Garmin, which wasn't very helpful

Garmin's answer:

> Hello, we verified that both ILS approaches for RWY 16 (Z and Y) show up on our GNS430w with the current Navigation data '2010'. Maybe the issue you had was resolved with the latest map update.